# Table is not updating. I used same syntax for updating other tables, but this one is not working

Tags: java, mysql, sql

This sql query is not updating the database, instead returning error. Any suggestions?

```
PreparedStatement ps10 = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE payroll_system.payslip SET hours_worked = (SELECT SUM(Hours) FROM payroll_system.monthly_timesheet WHERE employeeID=?) WHERE employeeID=?");
                    ps10.setString(1, employee_id);
                    ps10.setString(2, employee_id);
                    ps10.executeUpdate();
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show us your error message.

Comment: @user4759923 how to show that?

Comment: You should change your user name

Comment: Copy the error message and paste it here

Comment: Update your question and show the error message

Comment: @GeorgeJempty perhaps]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE payroll_system.payslip as t1 
    SET hours_worked = (SELECT SUM(Hours) FROM payroll_system.monthly_timesheet WHERE employeeID=t1.employeeID) 
    WHERE employeeID=?
```